# Is there any reason why a project has no settings.py file?

Tags: python, django

I have inherited a Django 1.4 project from an uncooperative developer and am having to find my way around and try and set up a dev environment.

One of the issues I am having is a result of the fact there is no settings.py file in the project. In the directory where I would expect to find it, there are files like *settings_production.py*, *settings_base.py* etc. but none called *settings.py*. So when I try

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it complains about this. I have renamed one of them to simply settings.py and I get a little further. But I am obviously missing something - is there a valid reason for this situation to arise and if so, is there something I need to do in my local setup to allow this to work?

Comment: perhaps try to create a generic `settings.py` (like the one you receive when you create a Django project) and then, inside settings.py, try to `import settings_base.py` or whatever other `*settings.py` file

Comment: Did you inherit any sort of build/deploy system as well?  I'd check there to see if he was folding together these configs then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly fine and used quite often. Different environments, like your local development environment and the actual production environment, often require different settings. You can pass the settings module to use to your manage.py command 
 or set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in your command line environment.

```
manage.py runserver --settings=import.path.to.settings
# or
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='import.path.to.settings'
```